# class with unique_ptr of vector to class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

How to implement a class containing a unique_ptr to a vector containing elements of the same class to build kind of a hierarchical structure.

I had implemented the same example using normal pointer before. That had worked fine.

Now I am trying to adapt to c++11 using unique_ptr.

The line marked with the "works" comment seems to do what I expect. The same kind of statement used inside the copy construct seems to fail copying the actual contents of the vector into the new instance.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Background information:

I have stripped down the class. The iPOD is only representing a lot of other members also existing within the class.
The class is used as representation of single attributes of an HMI widget tree.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


void func();

struct Attribute;

typedef std::vector<Attribute> AttributeVector;


struct Attribute
{

    int m_iPOD;

    //AttributeVector *m_kAttrVectorPtr; // Old version before unique_ptr did work...
    std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> m_kAttrVectorPtr; // New version using unique_ptr

    /** Default constructor.  */
    Attribute()
    : m_iPOD(-1), m_kAttrVectorPtr(nullptr)
    {
    }

    /** Constructs an attribute.  */
    Attribute(int iPOD, std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> kAttrs)
    : m_iPOD(iPOD), m_kAttrVectorPtr(std::move(kAttrs))
    {}

    /** Copy constructor.
     @param kSource Source instance.
     */
    Attribute(const Attribute& kSource)
    : m_iPOD(kSource.m_iPOD)
    {
        if(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr)
            m_kAttrVectorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> (new AttributeVector(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr));
        else
            m_kAttrVectorPtr = nullptr;
    }

    /** Assignment operator.
     @param kSource Source instance.
     */
    Attribute& operator=(const Attribute& kSource)
    {
        m_iPOD = kSource.m_iPOD;
        if(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr)
            m_kAttrVectorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> (new AttributeVector(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr));
        else
            m_kAttrVectorPtr = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Attribute& rkOther) const
    {
        return      m_iPOD == rkOther.m_iPOD; 
       // Todo real compare m_kAttrVectorPtr        == rkOther.m_kAttrVectorPtr;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Attribute& rkOther) const
    {
        return !operator==(rkOther);
    }
};

int main()
{
    AttributeVector kVector;
    Attribute kAttr1;

    kAttr1.m_iPOD = 101;
    kAttr1.m_kAttrVectorPtr = nullptr;

    Attribute kAttr2;

    kAttr2.m_iPOD=102;
    kAttr2.m_kAttrVectorPtr = nullptr;

    kVector.push_back(kAttr1);
    kVector.push_back(kAttr2);

    Attribute kAttr;

    kAttr.m_iPOD=100;
    kAttr.m_kAttrVectorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> (new AttributeVector(kVector)); // Works result= kattr with a vector of 2 attributes

    Attribute kAttrCopy(kAttr);// does not work. Only one entry within m_kAttrVectorPtr after copy instead of the 2 from above
    Attribute kAttrAssign;
    kAttrAssign = kAttr;// does not work. Only one entry within m_kAttrVectorPtr after copy instead of the 2 from above

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother storing the vector inside a `unique_ptr` at all?  You can just store the vector directly in your class.

Comment: I would instead have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Attribute>> m_kAttrVectorPtr`.

Comment: I don't see the point of using `std::unique_ptr` in your class, since you create new unique pointers in your copy constructor and assignment operator. You should not see the new smart pointers as pointers, instead think about them in terms of *ownership*. In fact, there no reason to use pointers *at all* for the vector, and it would simplify your code a lot since then you can just do e.g. `m_kAttrVector = kSource.m_kAttrVector` to copy the vectors.

Comment: `m_kAttrVectorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AttributeVector> (new AttributeVector(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr));` you use an `unique_ptr` to initial a `std::vector<Attribute>`, it will not work.

Comment: to Joachim Pileborg: The reason for the pointer/unique_ptr instead of directly embedding of the vector is that there are many instances of this class but only a few of them will need an own hierchy level with a vector.

Comment: So for the objects that don't need contents in the vector, keet it empty? An empty vector or a "null" `std::unique_ptr` object won't really make much difference, other than more complex code with the pointer approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `new AttributeVector(kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr)` with `new AttributeVector(*kSource.m_kAttrVectorPtr)`.

You can't construct a vector with any pointer, but with the value itself. (*)

Comment: I am wondering the whole time, why the program even compiles.

Comment: I have changed the code as ALittleDiff proposed and it now works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bernd I'm pretty sure, you stumbled over a compiler bug.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of `unique_ptr` is to manage an object on the heap, i.e. to automatically `delete` it once the pointer goes out of scope. A `vector` does the same with its contents, so allocating a `vector` on the heap is just a waste of resources (time and memory). This means that already your previous design which allocated a `vector` was flawed. Instead of

```
struct A {
  vector<A> *pvec;
  A() : pvec(new vector<A>) {}
  ~A() { delete pvec; }
};
```

(which you are attempting to improve with `unique_ptr`), simply use

```
struct A {
  vector<A> vec;     // requires 24 bytes on 64bit machines
  // auto generated constructor and destructor 
};
```

Alternatively, if the number of objects hold in the `vector` are known at the start, you could use a `unique_ptr`:

```
struct A {
  unique_ptr<A[]> vec;   // requires 8 bytes on 64bit machines
  A(size_t n)
  : vec(new A[n]) {}
};
```

Comment: Its not just an int. Its a whole struct with several members. And one of the members should be a vector of objects of the same kind. I see no chance with your proposal.

Comment: @BerndL. Why not? `struct A { vector<A> a; };` works perfectly well.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's an `int` or a *whole struct with several members*, because that's all on the heap. I have changed `int` to `A`.